# How to get user input for tictactoe game, by waiting for user message input in Discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I'm using `await bot.wait_for` inside a while loop. Despite the `await bot.wait_for`, the code just runs, infinitely awaiting `printBoard(ctx, board)`.

```py
@bot.command()
async def tictactoe(ctx, xo="X"):
    await ctx.send(
        "Enter your move according to this key till I figure out a better way:\nA1\tB1\tC1\t\nA2\tB2\tC2\t\nA3\tB3\tC3\t"
    )

    user = xo.upper
    board = ttt.initial_state()
    gameOver = ttt.terminal(board)

    while not gameOver:
        await printBoard(ctx, board)
        player = ttt.player(board)
        if user == player:
            await ctx.send(f"Play as {user}:")

            def check(msg):
                return (
                    msg.author == ctx.author
                    and msg.channel == ctx.channel
                    and msg.content.upper()
                    in ["A1", "B1", "C1", "A2", "B2", "C2", "A3", "B3", "C3"]
                )

            msg = await bot.wait_for("message", check=check, timeout=60.0)
            move = h.tttMoves[msg.content.upper()]

            print(move)
```

I want the script to pause at `await bot.wait_for` till it gets the user message (equivalent to how python waits for terminal input when using input()). How do I achieve this result?

Comment: Hi Could you pass the code for your printBoard function?

Answer (score 0):

i think If you give `unlimited timeout` , it will waits until get message